# Moving element with javascript - choppy effect in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll, safari, addeventlistener

Basically I'm trying to move an element based on the scroll position. The issue I have is that when scrolling on Firefox and Safari (MacOS) the element acts weird and choppy as the positioning doesn't update on time or something. Sometimes you need to scroll up and down few times to see it. Firefox has additional smoothing which makes things even uglier.

Element needs to be relatively positioned (needs to respect overflow: hidden).

The sample code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="block"></div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  height: 800vh;
  width: 100%;
}
#block{
  width: 300px;
  height:50px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JS:

```
var block = document.getElementById('block');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  block.style.top = window.pageYOffset*1.2 + "px";
});
```

And a CodePen link: https://codepen.io/maciejgunia/pen/gxQReo

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: here is the observed behaviour - I know some people see it differently - https://jumpshare.com/v/RhU7gNYAlMFwDo7HIl5Z

Comment: Here's what you should start with: https://johnresig.com/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Thanks, but I have updated the code according to the article and honestly the issue is even worse - now even in Chrome it is very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

add `transition: top 1s;` to `#block` CSS this will smooth out your animation

Comment: or however fast you want the transition to be.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the codepen code but it didn't fix the issue. Instead it really emphasized what is happening - the element is doing constant up and down motions - the reasoning for the choppiness. Any ideas how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: do you want to element to "move" of just stay fixed at the top?

Comment: you can make it   position:fixed;top:50px; that will make it stay at the top and not "float" around
you would have to get rid of the JS function if you do this

Comment: I want it to move but slower than the rest of the page, so it starts in one place and gradually moves down - kinda like a semi parallax effect. Position: fixed could be useful, but i need the element to hide at one point using overflow: hidden so only relative positioning is acceptable.